# The Array contain nil element or not?

Tags: ruby

```
array1= [{},nil,[]]
array2=[{},23,45]
```

These are my input
I used `.nil?` and `.empty?` function. The the both are gives `false`
but the first one is nil

I need help with this this

Comment: `nil?` checks whether the receiver _is_ `nil`, not if it contains it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`array.nil?` checks if array is nil, not if it contains a nil value. Similarly, `array.empty?` checks if array contains no elements.

If you want to check if any element is nil, use [`any?`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F).

```
array.any? { |element| element.nil? }
```

That can be shortened to `array.any?(nil)`.

Comment: Another (albeit less desirable) way: `arr != arr.compact`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland That's, uhh... why?

Comment: Why? Because it's there. OK, then how about `arr.any?(NilClass)`? Also, "shortened" may not be the right word.

Comment: @CarySwoveland `a.group_by(&:nil?).key?(true)` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you are mis-understanding the functionality of **.nil?** and **.empty?**. “.nil?” Will only return true for “nil” values i.e. “nil.nil? => true” but “[].nil? => false”.

Coming to “.empty?” if you see your variables “array1 and array2” both have some elements, it doesn’t matter if they have nil values, empty array or hashes, but what matters is both of them has 3 elements each. [This](https://blog.arkency.com/2017/07/nil-empty-blank-ruby-rails-difference/) will help you understanding the difference.